# How can I have a button with a border of one colour, then whitespace, then a border of another colour in android?

Tags: android, button, border

Like a rectangle with curved edges, some whitespace around it and then another rectangle with curved edges as the boundary for a button in Android?

Is it possible to do without images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a [9 patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) drawable.